# Skype not opening on Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, skype

Every time I go to launch Skype it'll make it look like it's loading but then no windows pop up. I think I've installed right because when I search for it the icon will come up. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Type `skype` in terminal, followed by `enter` key. If there's any issue you'll get an error message, that you can add to your question. If not skype should open directly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are issues with missing .so files. Can you check by starting skype from the terminal (try this: $ skype), and post the output?